# Can't get nested_form gem to work (javascript:void(0) error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, link-to, nested-form-for

This my first post here so try to bear with me. I'm trying to incorporate the nested_form gem into my Rails app. I have a Badge model which has many BadgeElements. I want to be able to dynamically add and remove BadgeElements, but I'm having trouble getting the gem to work properly. I don't know whether it's my setup or how I'm invoking it. (I've looked all over StackOverflow and Google for the answer and nothing has helped.) I've installed the "nested_form" gem (0.3.2) in my Gemfile, added the "//= require jquery_nested_form" line to my application.js, and changed my "form_for" to "nested_form_for", but the links to add and remove aren't working. When I click on them, I get a "javascript:void(0)" message. Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here are the relevant code bits for reference:

badge.rb:

```
class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :background, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :badge_elements, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :background
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :badge_elements, :allow_destroy => true
  validates :title, presence: true, length:{minimum: 3}
end
```

_form.html.haml:

```
= nested_form_for @badge, html:{class:"form-horizontal edit_badge", data:{id:@badge.id}} do |f| 
 %table{class: "table"}
   %tbody
     .form-group
       = render partial: "badge_elements/form", locals: {f:f}
       = f.link_to_add "Add an element", :badge_elements
```

badge_elements/_form.html.haml:

```
= f.fields_for :badge_elements do |j|
  %tr
    %td
    %td= j.label :side
    %td= j.text_field :side, id: "badge_element_#{j.object.id}_side"
  ...
  ...
  %tr
    %td
    %td= j.link_to_remove "remove element"
```

I'm running Rails 4. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!